# Bootstrap-table, x-editable and typeahead compatibility

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I use [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) and want to make cells editable with typeahead. In my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L7vgcx0/142/) cells are editable, but typeahead doesn't work.

**html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"  cellspacing="0" id="mainTable" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="name" >Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_cou nt" >Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description" >Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
var data = [{name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"},
           {name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"},
           {name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"}]

$('table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data
});

$('tr td').editable({
    mode: 'inline',
    typeahead: {
        local: ['Rome', 'Milan', 'Venice', 'Florence']
    }
});
```